# Replace object with in an array when checking for edits

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I am keeping track of the changes on a Mat table. And I am using Angular's `(change)` directive. Everytime there is a change I am pushing the entire row contents into an array. my problem is when the user updates the same row instead of replacing the contents it is adding another object to my array How do I correctly replcace the contents of the index specicified:

```
updateChanges(row){
   for(var i = 0; i < this.changes.length; i++){
     if(this.changes[i].cpiId == row.cpiId && this.changes[i] !== -1){
       this.changes[i] = row;
     }else{
      this.changes.push(row);
     }
   } 
   if(this.changes.length == 0){
    this.changes.push(row);
  }
   console.log(this.changes);
  }
```

Comment: `this.changes[i] !== 1` is suspect. Both conditions must be true in order to affect change. It is unlikely `this.changes[i]` equals `-1`.

Comment: Addtionally, [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) would be a really good candidate for you to consider for this task. Would take about one line of code.

Comment: I only added the `!== -1` to see if it would change anything but same results. I will check out the prototype.filter that you  mentioned thanks